# How to get files from the directory under Picture Library?

Tags: windows-8

I want to know how to get files from the directory under Picture Library.(C:\Users\username\Pictures\MyFoler)

I know how to get files and folders from PicturesLibrary.

```
StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;

IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileLists = await picturesFolder.GetFilesAsync();
IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> folderLists = await picturesFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same general mechanism, [StorageFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227230.aspx) exposes [GetFoldersAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfoldersasync.aspx) and [GetFilesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfilesasync.aspx).

This code, added after what you have, would get a list of files in Pictures\MyFolder

```
StorageFolder myFolder = folderLists.Where(f => f.DisplayName == "MyFolder").FirstOrDefault();
if (myFolder != null)
{
    ReadOnlyList<StorageFile> myPictures = await myFolder.GetFilesAsync();
}
```